# Hyperledger Fabric chaincode instantiation error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using fabric tools provided for composer to deploy fabric network as it deploys 1 peer, 1 orderer, 1 couchdb, & 1 fabric-ca. I am able to install chain code on peer but instantiation fails with following error. I am using command on fabric-peer.

`peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C composerchannel -n test -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}'`

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not
>   successful, error code 500, msg failed to execute transaction
>   83b806a14ec33d47e11950581357cc0ab05ef51dfb53d35c6b9f00eca7a49051:
>   timeout expired while starting chaincode test:1.0 for transaction
>   83b806a14ec33d47e11950581357cc0ab05ef51dfb53d35c6b9f00eca7a49051

And if I check the logs of orderer I get:

> 2018-09-01 11:09:16.205 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN
>   973 Error reading from 172.19.0.14:33674: rpc error: code = Canceled
>   desc = context canceled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check logs on node (VM) which host peer0 with:

```
docker ps -a
```

you will find chaincode container ID with exit code.

```
CONTAINER ID: **718e367bf1db**
IMAGE: dev-peer1-org1-**mycc-0.2**-9c1906
COMMAND: "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"
```

where ***mycc-0.2*** is you chaincode name and version. 
 Once you find the container ID - you can check the error log with:

```
docker logs <container_id>
```

I assume there is a bug in the your chaincode and the application can't start.

Comment: Thanks i figured out, package.json file was missing inside my chaincode folder and thats why container was not getting deployed

Answer (score 3):

in my case (windows 10) I stopped the network, removed all containers then restarted, worked fine:

```
$ docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$ docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm
$ ./startFabric.sh
```