# Fabric chaincode instantiation fails

Tags: macos, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Trying out the getting started guide from the [HyperLedger tutorials](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html#launch-the-network). It is pretty basic. Starting the network is the first step. Even the first  step is not working.

*Looked into script "startFabric.sh". Everything goes well, until "**chaincode** instantiation".*

```
2019-02-15 00:09:29.629 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> 
INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-02-15 00:09:29.629 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode fabcar:1.0 for transaction
```

Did this tutorial work for anyone?

Complete log of the script run.

```
$./startFabric.sh javascript

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Stopping cli                    ... done
Stopping peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Stopping orderer.example.com    ... done
Stopping couchdb                ... done
Stopping ca.example.com         ... done
Removing cli                    ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing couchdb                ... done
Removing ca.example.com         ... done
Removing network net_basic

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Creating ca.example.com         ... done
Creating orderer.example.com ... done
Creating couchdb             ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
2019-02-15 00:09:27.149 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2019-02-15 00:09:27.186 UTC [cli/common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Received block: 0
# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
2019-02-15 00:09:27.455 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2019-02-15 00:09:27.606 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted proposal to join channel
Creating cli ... done
chaincode install
2019-02-15 00:09:29.307 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-02-15 00:09:29.307 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
2019-02-15 00:09:29.354 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 003 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
chaincode instantiation
2019-02-15 00:09:29.629 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-02-15 00:09:29.629 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode fabcar:1.0 for transaction
```

Log from orderer,

```
2019-02-15 23:33:44.195 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 010 Error reading from 172.30.0.6:59028: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-02-15 23:35:31.556 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 011 Error reading from 172.30.0.6:59034: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
```

Comment: I would recommend you to remove all containers, prune network and volume as well, and try again. Just be careful before doing it, if you have something you don't want to erase.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the logs of containers too? I think you might try by setting `FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=50` inside `basic-network/start.sh`. If this doesnot work, we need to check the logs of container.

Comment: the command for it is ``docker logs <<container-name>>`` For example if you want to see the logs of the container ``peer0.org1.example.com`` then run command   ``docker logs peer0.org1.example.com``

Comment: The logs from orderer  `2019-02-15 23:35:31.556 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 011 Error reading from 172.30.0.6:59034: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled`

Comment: Can you also show the logs from peer through which you are installing and instantiating the chaincode?

Answer (score 1):

stop you network, remove all containers and restart network. It worked for me, when i had faced the issue on ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$ docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm
$ ./startFabric.sh
```

It also works on windows [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56437883/10239067)